# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'. when importing glumpy

Tags: python, numpy, conda, glumpy

```
>>> import glumpy
/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/clean-pvnet/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glumpy/gloo/variable.py:82: FutureWarning: In the future `np.bool` will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar.
  gl.GL_BOOL         : ( 1, gl.GL_BOOL,         np.bool),
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/clean-pvnet/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glumpy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import app
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/clean-pvnet/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glumpy/app/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . console import Console
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/clean-pvnet/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glumpy/app/console.py", line 7, in <module>
    from glumpy import gl, glm, gloo
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/clean-pvnet/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glumpy/gloo/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . program import Program
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/clean-pvnet/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glumpy/gloo/program.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . variable import gl_typeinfo, Uniform, Attribute
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/clean-pvnet/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glumpy/gloo/variable.py", line 82, in <module>
    gl.GL_BOOL         : ( 1, gl.GL_BOOL,         np.bool),
  File "/home/mona/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 324, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'.
`np.bool` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations. Did you mean: 'bool_'?
```

I changed the following file line `(clean-pvnet) mona@ada:~/anaconda3/envs/clean-pvnet/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glumpy$ vi gloo/variable.py`

`bool        gl.GL_BOOL         1  gl.GL_BOOL         np.bool`

to

`bool        gl.GL_BOOL         1  gl.GL_BOOL         np.bool_`

and still same error.

It seems the module is not being reloaded despite opening a new terminal tab and `conda activate clean-pvnet`.

Comment: The last `glumpy` version is outdated, try the master from github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only converted one of the `np.bool`s to `np.bool_` following a tutorial. I searched for all of them and converted them similarly and error is gone.

```
(clean-pvnet) mona@ada:~/anaconda3/envs/clean-pvnet/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glumpy$ rg np.bool_
gloo/variable.py
22:bool        gl.GL_BOOL         1  gl.GL_BOOL         np.bool_
23:bvec2       gl.GL_BOOL_VEC2    2  gl.GL_BOOL         np.bool_
24:bvec3       gl.GL_BOOL_VEC3    3  gl.GL_BOOL         np.bool_
25:bvec4       gl.GL_BOOL_VEC4    4  gl.GL_BOOL         np.bool_
82:    gl.GL_BOOL         : ( 1, gl.GL_BOOL,         np.bool_),
83:    gl.GL_BOOL_VEC2    : ( 2, gl.GL_BOOL,         np.bool_),
84:    gl.GL_BOOL_VEC3    : ( 3, gl.GL_BOOL,         np.bool_),
85:    gl.GL_BOOL_VEC4    : ( 4, gl.GL_BOOL,         np.bool_),
```

Comment: While effective, I would not recommend this approach in general. Conda uses hardlinks to minimize disk usage and this effectively changes the package everywhere, including the package cache. One may think this good (fixes it everywhere), but it will likely result in subsequent corrupt file warnings, is not exportable, and breaks operations like `conda-pack`. Instead, just install the patched version from GitHub (`pip install git+https://...`) or [downgrade NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77521907/570918). Either of those can still be captured with `conda env export`.

Comment: Now you can also install the updated version `pip install glumpy==1.2.1` to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

`glumpy` has been updated, so just do

```
pip install glumpy==1.2.1
```

**OLD ANSWER**

The underlying issue is that `glumpy` just has `numpy` in its requirements, while in reality, it should be `numpy<1.24`, so one solution can also be to just downgrade numpy. Depending on if you installed it by conda/pip, use

```
pip/conda install numpy<1.24
```